# Scrollable widget not filled

Tags: android, android-widget, greendao

I tried to get a resizeable widget working, but it won't. I've got a database which I use with greenDAO. So my app should work on Android 2.3+. That's why I want to have got the following widgets:

- 4x2 with 2 items
- 4x3 with 3 items
- 4x4 with 4 items
- 4x5 with 5 items

In preHoneycomb these `Widgets` should just show the first items and opens the app on click.

In Android 3+ these `widgets` should be realizable and scrollable. My problem is that my Widget Service class is never called. So nothing inside the widget will be filled :-

Here is my code:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String TAG = "WidgetProvider";

@TargetApi(14)
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Update!!");

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimetableActivity_.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);

        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent
                .toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_widget_home, pendingIntent);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.btn_widget_refresh, svcIntent);

        Intent update = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, update,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_widget_refresh, pend);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}


@TargetApi(11)
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    private static final String TAG = "WidgetService";

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "WidgetService called");

        return new ListRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(),
                (TimetableApplication_) this.getApplication(), intent);
    }
}

class ListRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private static final String TAG = "ListRemoteViewsFactory";

    private Context mContext;

    private TimetableApplication_ application;
    private List<Events> events = new ArrayList<Events>();

    public ListRemoteViewsFactory(Context context,
            TimetableApplication_ application, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.application = application;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, ""+getCount());

        String title = "";
        String description = "";
        Events e;

        if ((e = events.get(position)) != null) {
            title = e.getSubjects().getTitle();
            description = e.getStart().toGMTString();
        }

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_item);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_widget_item_title, title);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_widget_item_description, description);

        return rv;
    }

    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        if (events != null) {
            events.clear();
        }

        events = application.getEvents();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }
}
```

And here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.mprengemann.hwr.timetabel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".TimetableApplication_"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/TimetableTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TimetableActivity_"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PreferenceActivity_"
            android:label="@string/menu_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SubjectDetailActivity_" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetprovider" />
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".widget.WidgetService" />
        <service android:name=".widget.ListWidgetService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I realise this is an old post but it could be that your problem is that you haven't included a required permission for your widget sevice in the manifest file....

You could try changing:

```
<service android:name=".widget.WidgetService" />
```

To

```
<service android:name=".widget.WidgetService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```